# Setting up resque-pool over a padrino Rakefile throwing errors

Tags: activerecord, rack, resque, padrino

I have setup a **Padrino** bus application using super-cool **Resque** for handling background process and **ResqueBus** for pub/sub of events.

The **ResqueBus** setup creates a resque queue and a worker for it to work on. Everything upto here works fine. Now since the resquebus is only creating a single worker for a single queue, and the process in my bus app can go haywire since many events will be published and subscribed. So a single worker per application queue seems to be inefficient. So thought of integrating the resque-pool gem to handle the worker process.

*I have followed all process that resque pool gem has specified. I have edited my Rakefile.*

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake. 

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Ojus::Application.load_tasks

require 'resque/pool/tasks'

# this task will get called before resque:pool:setup
# and preload the rails environment in the pool manager

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  # generic worker setup, e.g. Hoptoad for failed jobs
end

task "resque:pool:setup" do

  # close any sockets or files in pool manager

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  # and re-open them in the resque worker parent
  Resque::Pool.after_prefork do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

end
```

*Now I tried to run this resque-pool command.*

```
resque-pool --daemon --environment production
```

*This throws an error like this.*

/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@notification-engine/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'default_env' database is not configured. Available: [:development, :production, :test] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

I tried to debug this and found out that it throws an error at line

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
```

For now I have removed this line and everything seems working fine. But due to this a problem  may arise because if we restart the padrino application the older ActiveRecord connection will be hanging around.

**

> I just wanted to know if there is any work around for this problem and
>   run the resque-pool command by closing all the ActiveRecord
>   connections.

**

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you had given your database.rb file of padrino.

Never mind, you can try 
`defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) && ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!`
instead of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

and

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Padrino.env])
```

instead of ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection()

to establish a connection with activerecord you have to pass a parameter to what environment you want to connect otherwise it will search 'default_env' which is default in activerecord.
checkout the source code [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/11c697383e6fea7834ee1a8ba2815ff0da20f0fe/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb)